# jquery simplify selection for onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, onclick

Something looks wrong (inefficient?) with:

```
$($('.feature-s').siblings()).children().children('a[data-target=#deleteModal]').parent().parent().click();
```

I want to select the span where:

```
/html/body/div/div/div/div[1][class="feature-s"]
/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/span/a/i/span <= click
```

But not where:

```
/html/body/div/div/div/div[1][class="something else"]
/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/span/a/i/span <= not handled
```

I recreated the situations here:

http://jsfiddle.net/brianray/ncu6u/

If my selector is fine, just say so. I just feel like there must be a better way to select that button based on the existing dom.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest and fastest (out of all the other answers) is:

```
$('.feature-s + div a[data-target="#deleteModal"]')
```

See [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/selector-performance-test-mt):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

check the jsFiddle below. You can directly select the elements that come directly after feature-s using the + selector.

```
$('.feature-s + div').find('a[data-target="#deleteModal"]').click(function(){
    alert('hey');
    return false;
});
```

The sample below works just fine and is more efficient.

http://jsfiddle.net/ncu6u/1/

Comment: Believe it or not, that's actually 6% slower! Looks better though http://jsperf.com/selector-performance-test-mt

Comment: Shouldve mentioned, more effecient code wise, not performance wise. .find() is a hog when it comes to performance!

Comment: @mattytommo 6% on startup but who cares since it happens in the back ground?

Comment: Chris is right I was looking for better code. However, I do think we should know the the speed impact implications so I am glad @mattytommo mentioned this. Thanks!

Comment: @brianray Did you see my answer? With slight tweaks to this answer, you can make it even faster and simpler :)

Comment: This is pretty nice, but in the question the event handler is attached to the anchors parent parent, which would be `.feature-setup-button`, not that it looks like it would matter in the posted example, just noting it.

Comment: @mattytommo yes I saw and I accepted that answer. Thank you to you both.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
$('.feature-s').siblings()
```

already returns jQuery object so you don't have to wrap it into the $().

All in all seems fine. Hope this helps.

Comment: I think its a little long for one-liner but it should be faster than anything i can think of.....